# Blinking text in progressbar?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, visual-c#-express-2010

i have made a cool progressbar with text in the middle of it. Here is my code:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Increment(+1);
    int percent = progressBar1.Value;
    progressBar1
        .CreateGraphics()
        .DrawString(
            percent.ToString() + "%", 
            new Font("Arial", (float)8.25, FontStyle.Regular), 
            Brushes.Black, 
            new PointF(progressBar1.Width / 2 - 10, 
            progressBar1.Height / 2 - 7)
        );
    if (progressBar1.Value >= 99)
    {
        timer2.Stop();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

For some reason, the text shows up then disappears and other weird stuff. Why is that, and how do i fix it?

Comment: *I felt a great disturbance in the Force, as if millions of end users cried out in terror and were suddenly silenced.*

Comment: I have the speed i like, the progress bar is smooth, but the text blinks a lot...

Comment: It is probably a double buffer issue, you should do a search on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the drawing code into the Paint event, you are basically modifying the control's visuals, so you need to handle this instead of the default painting behaviour.

Comment: The Paint event can be overridden in code.

Just edit your source code, write override, and choose Paint from the IntelliSense list.

Comment: is there a paint event for the progressbar? i have tried to add the code in the form's paint, but that did not work

Answer (score 0):

Your drawing gets erased whenever the control is repainted.

Instead, you need to set a flag indicating whether to draw the text right now, then handle the `Paint` event, and, if the flag is true, draw the text.

In the timer tick handler, toggle the flag and call `Invalidate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to create a UserControll and use a label on top of the progress bar, and use each separately, this might prove easier to do, hardly any additional code will be needed for this.

Comment: well, the label will not be transparent...i need it transparent

Comment: then set the label's background as transparent

Comment: that will not work, because it will grab the background color of the form...i have tried that...try it and you will see it does not work

Comment: I'll try it and get back to you later